# C# .Net can access the bcdboot commands via Process()

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, process, arguments

Im trying to copy UEFI files onto a SD Card and Im trying to use Process to do most of the tasks I need to do for this to work but It seems that bcdboot command works when using the same command in the CMD Window but when you open cmd.exe via process and give it the same command it doesn't work, I've tried everything possible I think and cant seem to get it working :(

Code -:

```
            string[] bcdArgs = new string[3];
            bcdArgs[0] = "bcdboot " + @"i:\windows /s p: /f UEFI";

            Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            foreach (string arg in bcdArgs)
            {
                cmd.StartInfo.Arguments += arg;
            }

            cmd.Start();

            //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

            cmd.WaitForExit();

            if (cmd.HasExited)
            {
                signWindowsFiles();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you're using a fully-qualified filename. Calls to %SystemRoot% (ie: C:\Windows\System32) are re-directed when running a 32-bit process on 64-bit windows. Instead of 'C:\Windows\System32' the call is re-directed to 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64'. Need to override this behavior by using "Sysnative" in place of "System32".

Instead of "C:\Windows\system32\diskpart.exe", use "C:\Windows\Sysnative\diskpart.exe".

```
//Check if OS is 64-bit and this program is running
//as 32-bit.
//
//Note: For a 64-bit process, IntPtr.Size = 8
//      For a 32-bit process, IntPtr.Size = 4


string folderSys32Path = string.Empty;

//Windows folder (ex: C:\Windows)
string folderWinPath = Path.GetFullPath(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"));

//get system32 folder path
if (System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem && IntPtr.Size == 4)
{
    //using "Sysnative" in place of "System32"
    //ensures that the 64-bit "System32" folder is
    //used instead of "SysWOW64"
    folderSys32Path = Path.Combine(folderWinPath, "Sysnative");
}//if
else
{
    folderSys32Path = Path.Combine(folderWinPath, "System32");
}//else
```

Also, you may need to use an Application Manifest file, specifying that it's required to run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

You are running `cmd.exe bcdboot i:\windows /s p: /f UEFI` which won't work. You need to add `/c` after cmd.exe.

From `cmd.exe /?`

```
Starts a new instance of the Windows command interpreter

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

-> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
...
```

Modified code:

```
        string[] bcdArgs = new string[3];
        bcdArgs[0] = "/c"; // cmd.exe args
        bcdArgs[1] = "bcdboot.exe " + @"i:\windows /s p: /f UEFI"; // bcdboot.exe

        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        cmd.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        foreach (string arg in bcdArgs)
        {
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments += arg + " "; // Adds a space after every argument
        }

        cmd.Start();

        //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        cmd.WaitForExit();

        if (cmd.HasExited)
        {
            signWindowsFiles();
        }
```

(CODE UNTESTED, edits are appreciated)

Comment: I'll test this, in the project

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your arguments by spaces. Instead of:

```
foreach (string arg in bcdArgs)
{
    cmd.StartInfo.Arguments += arg;
}
```

Try this:

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", bcdArgs);
```

Also, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bcdboot-command-line-options-techref-di), for some options you might need to run with administrator privileges. So if it still doesn't work try again as administrator.

Comment: I do have admin privs set on this application including using the cmd.startinfo.verb = "runas"

Comment: nope not working, even tho I did use 'cmd.startinfo.verb = "runas" ' to force admin control

Comment: I keep getting 'bcdboot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.in the debugger

Comment: Try the full path to the exe rather than depending on it being in the environment path.