c# to launch .bat that launches powershell
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "C:\\tmp\\Support\\InstallIIS.bat",
            Verb = "runas", // Request admin rights
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
}

InstallIIS.bat content:
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server,Web-ASP,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Metabase,Web-Windows-Auth,Web-Mgmt-Console,Web-Dyn-Compression"

I got this bat file in the C:\\tmp\\Support\\InstallIIS.bat file. A console app with the above code launches it and another console window appears where I see the PowerShell command. Almost at once, it closes.
If I run the InstallIIS.bat manually, it does what it has to - installs IIS. With C# code, it does not.
My question is: how to make C# ⇾ bat ⇾ PowerShell work?
Trying to accomplish another, more complex task, I simplified the issue to the most basic level. So, I am stuck with the problem that in my view does not have to exist
Update: a similar question 'Get-WindowsDriver' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet does not help as I'm trying to avoid using PowerShell calls inside my code. I've got to stick with C# -> bat -> PowerShell calls

This question is similar to: 'Get-WindowsDriver' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your update seems to contradict the title to your post: c# to launch .bat that launches powershell. It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. It's better to describe what you're trying to accomplish rather than how you're trying to accomplish it - particularly since it seems that you may not know the best way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.

Seems kinda ludicrous that you would use C# to eventually run a powershell script, when powershell is basically C#

"Almost at once, it closes." - put pause as the last line in the bat, so you can see what it says. My guess is, since you haven't mentioned getting a UAC prompt, that it's not running as admin and doesn't have permissions. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767759/processstartinfo-verb-runas-not-working and Sunder's own answer help?

@TessellatingHeckler. Thank you so much! Here is the output
Install-WindowsFeature : The term 'Install-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Install-WindowsFeature -Name Web-Server,Web-ASP,Web-Basic-Auth,Web-Me ...

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-WindowsFeature:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



@TessellatingHeckler would you suggest why it bat produces this kind of output only if called from c#?

@Itallmakescents, I am thankful for your comment! My goal is to make c# launch .bat file that has powershell command that installs IIS with the code provided in my original question. If you have any idea why .bat output when called manually differs from the c# call, please don't hesitate to contribute. I'd really appeciate that!

What an odd thing to do. Why run a batch to run Powershell, why not just run powershell.exe directly? Even better, you can run Powershell direct from C# using Powershell.Create. "I'm trying to avoid using PowerShell calls inside my code" why?

To make it work, do in Visual Studio:
Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer
Select "Properties"
Go to the "Build" tab
Look for "Platform target"
Change from "Any CPU" to "x64"
explanation
I've followed suggestion of TessellatingHeckler to put a pause at the end of the .bat. The cmd windows paused, I did few tests and in one of them run another instance of the cmd invoked by c#. This other instance had "Administrator: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe in the title. Such a thing happens when c# code is intended to run on x32 rather than x64 platform.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146532/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787416/10024425

Good find; that's nothing like I was expecting!
